# Classification of Matrices and normal forms

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, jordan-normal-form

As is shown in couses of Linear Algebra, for every square matrix $A$ one can choose $S,T,P\in GL(n,K)$ so that $SAT^{-1}=\operatorname{diag}(1,...1,0,...,0)$ and $PAP^{-1}$ is in Jordan normal form. But what if $S,T,P$ are also restricted to being orthogonal? Are there also special forms $A$ can be transformed to then?
And what about bi-linear forms? It is shown that with $S\in GL(n,K)$, one can transform the matrix representation $A$ of a symmetric bi-linear form to $SAS^T=\operatorname{diag}(1,...,1,-1,...,-1,0,...,0)$, but what about non-symmetric bi-linear forms, orthogonal $S$ or transformations like $SAT^T?$
I know that's a lot of questions, I'd also be very happy about partial answers or helpful links.

Comment: If $S$ and $T$ are restricted to being orthogonal or unitary, then the normal form in that case is called the [singular value decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition)

Comment: Thanks! I just realized too that for orthogonal matrices $P^{-1}=P^T $ anyway, so there is nothing special in the case of bilinear forms and orthogonal matrices. But what about $PAP^{-1}$ with just one orthogonal matrix P?